# Obtaining logical name of the entity

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using late bound and as an account is created, I'm creating a phone call too. I also found a very [useful example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx) doing almost that. The only thing that bothers me is that the following lines:

```
if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
{
  Guid id = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
  String type = "account";
  followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(type, id);
}
```

assume that the cause of the phone call is an account. Well, it is, but in the future it might be not. I tried to get the type as follows:

```
if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
{
  Guid id = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
  String type = context.OutputParameters["logicalname"] as String;
  followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(type, id);
}
```

but then I got error telling me that such a field doesn't exist. Is the field name wrong? Or am I using all the wrong approach to retrieve the logical name of the entity (i.e. the actual name of the entity type, be that account, contacts or a crazydonkeyass)?

Also, I'm not entirely sure if *OutputParameters* is the right place to look in. Suggestions?

Comment: How is this plugin registered? `OutputParameters` will very based on the message and mode.

Comment: @Nicknow It's registered on *Create* and *Update*, post-event, synchronized. Does it open for an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in `context.PrimaryEntityName`

**EDIT**

Here's the bit from the example that checks if this is account

```
// Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

// Verify that the target entity represents an account.
// If not, this plug-in was not registered correctly.
if (entity.LogicalName != "account")
    return;
```

I guess that's why they have account hardcoded (ugly!)

Comment: Right? That's what I thought too. But check out the link to MS. They clearly suggest a different approach. I get my stuff mostly from *InputParameters* but they go with *OutputParameters*. Can't determine if it's just a poof by MS or a new and better way to do stuff in CRM 2013...

Comment: Can you paste the link?

Comment: `OutputParameters` are not new for 2013 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673(v=crm.5).aspx#bkmk_inputandoutput) - I believe this answer is correct is the Plugin is registered on a Create or Update.

Comment: @Nicknow Oh, sorry for being unclear. I knew that *OutputParameters* were there before. I just never got to use them. I always go for the stuff in *Target* and *InputParameters*. Once or twice I've browsed for the differences between ins and outs but the info I got (surely a correct definition) didn't make me any smarter. I also answered to your other comment. :)

Comment: @MarioZG Are you referring to the link with the example? Check the question again, second line, first two words ("useful example" it says). Perhaps I should have written "link" explicitly. Sorry.

Comment: @KonradViltersten sorry - me being blind. I have added few comments to answer

Comment: Don't sweat it. We all do that on occasion. Last August I asked a SQL-question. The very first responder: "Didn't you ask this question a year ago?". Would you believe it?! I did! Exactly (on the week) the same time a year before. Had no idea. Didn't get it on Google. Embarrassed like a shaved dog...   :)